# Generate TFS query url for a specifc set of tags

Tags: c#, tfs

I have a c# webapp which is a build tool for my company. We want to be able to show a URL which answers which workitems were addressed in this build. We have the users use a TFS tag value for the build. So what we want is to use a stored query and pass it the TFS tag. I'm assuming that the querystring would have the tag value that I'm looking for. We currently do something similar with changesets: https://tfs.corp.inc/tfs/DefaultCollection/CorpInc/_versionControl/changeset?id=74682

We want to have something similar for workitems. We want that url. Can anyone help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: The link is broken. Can you clarify it more detailed or add an example to explain what feature you want to achieve?

Comment: @Kathy Lori, which step you're in now? 1). Do you already get the method to get associated work items from TFS build? 2). Are all associated work items are tagged with specific tag? 3). And is there one available stored query which is used to query work items applied with specific tag?

Comment: All associated work items would have a specific tag. But I was wondering if I create a query for workitems for tag X, will other people be able to run this query? Also, it said that query urls expire after 90 days. My app would have these urls baked in, so I don't know if that would work.

Answer (score 0):

1). To get associated work items in one specific TFS build, you need to firstly use the [InformationNodeConverters.GetAssociatedChangesets(IBuildDetail)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc339559(v=vs.120).aspx) method to get the assoicated changesets. Then use the [Changeset.WorkItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changeset.workitems(v=vs.120).aspx) property to get the associated work items. Check this MSDN case link for the details: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/92766815-c09b-422b-91fc-5e745e3aaa21/tfs-2010-how-to-query-workitems-by-build?forum=tfsgeneral

2). After these associated work items are found and applied with specific tags, and there is one saved query to list all work items with that tag. To get URL with that work item query, one simplest method is open that work item query in TFS web access, and then click "Copy query URL". You will then get the work item query URL to be similar to: https://tfs.corp.inc/tfs/DefaultCollection/CorpInc/_workitems?tempQueryId=b124db9d-26e5-4a5c-94c7-0233d99faf56

[image]